# RoR | POST запрос возращает 422 ошибку

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, post, mvc, ruby

Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой. При попытке отправить пост запрос (создать, обновить новости на сайте) получаю 422 ответ от сервера.
Началось это несколько месяцев назад, при этом такая проблема наблюдается во всех браузерах кроме FireFox, в нём работает всё нормально.
Возможно кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным? (логи посмотреть к сожалению не могу)

Answer (score 1):

Вариаций почему так происходит может быть множество.

1. Когда объект имеет ошибки и вы отвечаете в формате JSON, вы всегда будете получать статус 422.

Вам нужно понять, почему у вашего объекта были ошибки. И это может быть что угодно.

2. CSRF валидация. 
   Уберите проверку CSRF токена в текущем контроллере

`skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`

3. Добавьте токен в представление.

`<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

4. Если используете AJAX

   ```
   $.ajax({
      type: "post", 
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', 
      $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
      url: "/form_submit/<%= @form.id %>" ,
      data: form_data, 
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
         console.log("this is success");
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      }
    });
   ```

Но не факт, что вышеперечисленное поможет. Нужен конкретный код по вашему случаю.